# How to redirect probing for assemblies in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application that is located in `App` folder. And I'm not using Kestrel or IIS Express to run it. Rather we have an infrastructure that hosts that `App` folder directly in IIS and does more things to make our development environment very similar to our production environment (DevOps).

Things work just fine. When I build, the output goes into `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0` folder and we have a `Web.config` file in which we have configured our `AspNetCoreModule` to load the entry DLL from that path.

Now I want to use `ClosedXML`, which has a dependency upon `System.Drawing.Common` library.

When I build and test my application, I have this error:

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest 
>   (App.deps.json) was not found:
>       package: 'System.Drawing.Common', version: '4.5.0-preview1-25914-04'
>       path: 'runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0/System.Drawing.Common.dll'

The point is, I have a `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0` folder that hosts the application, and I can confirm that `System.Drawing.Common` is already copied there. Yet seems that MSBuild doesn't copy it to the intended `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.0` folder.

I can copy the requested library to the given folder, that is `runtime/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0`, and the app will work just fine.

I can add additional probing paths to my `App.runtimeconfig.json`.

I can change the searching path for this library in my `App.deps.json` to the same directory.

But these are all done manually.

How can I make the build process copy the dependencies to their correct locations?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Publish` command to create your output directory.  Either using `dotnet publish` from the command line, or in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, right click your project -> Publish.

When you just `Build` your app, the dependent assemblies that come from NuGet packages stay in the NuGet cache folder.  And when you F5/dotnet run your app they are loaded from the NuGet cache folder.  But if you want your application folder to be ready to run in a different environment outside of VS/dotnet run, then you should be publishing your app.